# how to find simple field extension $\mathbb{F_2}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How would I find a field extension of $\mathbb{F_2}$ that has $4$ elements?

Would $x^2$ work?
 Since $0$ and $1$ are elements already and then $x$ and $x^2$ are units of the class?
PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 1):

First find a degree 2 polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ that is irreducible. ($x^2 + x + 1$ works well).

Then $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2 + x + 1)$ gives a field of 4 elements. As finite fields are unique, then this is *the* field of order $4$ and hence $\mathbb{F}_2$ is contained in it.